# For Loop Not executing after If statements

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, coordinates, jython

I am trying to draw a face in jython.

I am using If not Elif statements so each color is overwritten and I build up a face with layer upon layer.

```
def face():
  pic=makeEmptyPicture(400,400)

  for x in range (400):
    for y in range (400):
      px = getPixel(pic,x,y)
      setColor(px, makeColor(43, 170, 214))
      #face
      if (( pow((x-200),2)+pow((y-200),2))<pow(200,2)):
        setColor(px, makeColor (255, 214, 153))
      #eyes
      if( ((pow((x-100),2)+pow((y-160),2))<pow(50,2)) or ((pow((x-290),2)+pow((y-145),2))<pow(60,2)) ):
        setColor(px,makeColor(255,255,255))
      #iris
      if( ((pow((x-100),2)+pow((y-163),2))<pow(20,2)) or ((pow((x-295),2)+pow((y-135),2))<pow(22,2)) ):
        setColor(px,makeColor(54, 123, 220))
      #pupil
      if( ((pow((x-100),2)+pow((y-165),2))<pow(10,2)) or ((pow((x-295),2)+pow((y-137),2))<pow(11,2)) ):
        setColor(px,makeColor(0,0,0))
      #nose
      if( ((pow((x-209),2)+pow((y-245),2))<pow(13,2)) or ((pow((x-191),2)+pow((y-250),2))<pow(12,2)) ):
        setColor(px,makeColor(255, 198, 114))
      #mouth
      for y in range (337,311):
        x = (y-337)*(247-181)/(311-337) +181
        setColor(px,makeColor(254, 114, 115))

  return (pic)
```

I am getting this:
[image: face]
What I want is this:

[image: face2]

It appears this is not executing:

```
#mouth
for y in range (337,311):
   x = (y-337)*(247-181)/(311-337) +181
   setColor(px,makeColor(254, 114, 115))
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: A programmer **AND** an artist! Hey Skippy, glad you found a solution to your other question, *cheers!*

Comment: Will do, and good to see you too. Hope you're getting fine weather, cheers :)

Comment: Very interesting area of StackExchange. I didn't know areas as such existed (I don't go out much, but when I do, I make it count.). Now, you've "picked my brain/curiosity" ;-) I'm sure you/everyone will be hearing from me (GRIN), in a good way of course.

Comment: We're mid-way into summer here, so we're next! Oh well, at least this year, I won't have to be splitting/piling any more firewood, neither will I have to shovel any snow, at least... not 4-6 feet of it anyway, from previous years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run a range *backwards,* you need to provide a step of `-1`.

For example:

```
pax> python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 16:53:07) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print range (50,40)
[]
>>> print range (50,40,-1)
[50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41]
>>>
```

Without the negative step, the range never starts because the end value has already been passed.

So, in your particular case, you want:

```
for y in range (337,311,-1):
   x = (y-337)*(247-181)/(311-337) +181
   setColor(px,makeColor(254, 114, 115))
```

However, the way you're doing it is also not ... what I would call a paragon of efficiency - that's about as tactful as I can be :-)

You're drawing the entire mouth for every single one of the 160,000 pixels you process. You may want to consider some less primitive drawing functions like lines and circles, along the following lines:

- draw a big blue square.
- draw a big pink circle for the face.
- draw two white circles for the outer eyes.
- draw two blue circles for the inner eyes.
- draw two black circles for the irises.
- draw two orangey circles for the nose.
- draw a purple line for the mouth.

I suspect that's going to be somewhat more efficient than individually setting every single pixel based on a series of rules.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass -1 as the third argument to `range`.

**Demo:**

```
>>> range(10, 5)
[]
>>> range(10, 5, -1)
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6]
```

**Code:**

```
for y in range (337, 311, -1):            #311 is not inclusive
     x = (y-337)*(247-181)/(311-337) +181
     setColor(px,makeColor(254, 114, 115))
```